# Ideal way to store multiple texts in mongoose with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose, schema

I've been building a mongoose schema for texts that will be displayed across different pages, and it has end point to POST data for updating the texts.

**For example, I would like to store text messages that will be displayed/updated in About Page and Contact Page**

What would be the **preferred way** of designing the text model?

**1) Model that has all messages stored in one data object**

- In front-end, the parent component fetches all text messages with **Texts.findOne()** and trickles down to pages that need it

```js
const textsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    aboutMessage1: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    aboutMessage2: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    contactMessage1: {
      type: String
    },
    contactMessage2: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**2) Model that contains each message--so it will have multiple objects**

- In fron-end, each page uses **Text.findById(textId)** to retrieve each message

```js
const textSchema = new Schema(
  {
    // Example: name = contactMessage
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    message: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**3) Multiple models that contains texts for each page**

- Similar to **1)** approach, texts get fetched with **Texts.findOne()**, but performed in each page

```js
const aboutTextsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    message1: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    message2: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const contactTextsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    message1: {
      type: String,
    },
    message2: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most promising option is the second one. Because first and third options are static, and if in the future, you need to add a new page or or a new message to an existing page, it will require changes in the mongoose model, and deployment for API.

But I think, instead of creating a text schema, it would better to create a page schema for your scenario.

Here I embed messages inside the page schema.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const pageSchema = new Schema(
  {
    page: {
      type: String
    },
    messages: [
      new Schema({
        name: {
          type: String
        },
        message: {
          type: String
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Page", pageSchema);
```

Now we can use this post route to create a page:

```js
router.post("/pages", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Text.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});
```

We can create a page and its messages using the previous post route.

Request Body:

```
{
    "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162890",
    "page": "About",
    "messages": [
        {
            "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162892",
            "name": "Abou1",
            "message": "About1 message..."
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162891",
            "name": "Abou2",
            "message": "About2 message..."
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-02-16T12:39:05.154Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-16T12:39:05.154Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162890",
    "page": "About",
    "messages": [
        {
            "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162892",
            "name": "Abou1",
            "message": "About1 message..."
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162891",
            "name": "Abou2",
            "message": "About2 message..."
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-02-16T12:39:05.154Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-16T12:39:05.154Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

If later we want to add a message to a page we can use the following put route.

```js
router.put("/pages/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Page.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $push: { messages: req.body }
    },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.send(result);
});
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "name": "Abou3",
    "message": "About3 message..."
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162890",
    "page": "About",
    "messages": [
        {
            "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162892",
            "name": "Abou1",
            "message": "About1 message..."
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e4937e9e2454a2c0c162891",
            "name": "Abou2",
            "message": "About2 message..."
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e493926f905ab3300106f94",
            "name": "Abou3",
            "message": "About3 message..."
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-02-16T12:39:05.154Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-16T12:44:22.763Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

When client needs a page's messages, all we need to do is retrieving the page by it's id or page name:

```js
router.get("/pages/id/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Page.findById(req.params.id);
  res.send(result);
});

//or

router.get("/pages/name/:name", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Page.findOne({ page: req.params.name });
  res.send(result);
});
```